# Getting null pointer exception while adding data to database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got a nullpointer exception while adding data to the database.
My  java file is pasted here,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    findViewById();

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!etPassword.getText().toString().equals(etConfPassword.getText().toString())){
                 displayToast("Please confirm Password");
            }else if(etUserName.getText().toString().equals("")){
                displayToast("Please enter Login ID");
            }else if(etPassword.getText().toString().equals("")){
                displayToast("Please enter Password");
            }else if(isExisting(etFirstName.getText().toString(), "loginId", "UserDetails")){
                displayToast("This User already exist");
            }else{
                    handleDB();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Replay.class));   
            }
       }    
   });    
}
private void handleDB() {
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("firstName", etFirstName.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("lastName", etLastName.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("loginId", etUserName.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("cofmPassword", etConfPassword.getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("emailAddress", etEmailAddress.getText().toString());
        Replay.database.insert("UserDetails", null, contentValues);
    } catch(SQLiteException se ){
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");}}
        private void displayToast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
private void findViewById(){
    etFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FName);
    etLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LName);
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginId);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    etConfPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConfPassword);
    etEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
}};
```

and the error log is

```
10-15 08:51:55.932: E/AndroidRuntime(606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 08:51:55.932: E/AndroidRuntime(606): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 08:51:55.932: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at com.GenioCode.replay.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:38)
10-15 08:51:55.932: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-15 08:51:55.932: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
```

After the compilation database is created without any content.
Please help me to identify the error..

Comment: what code is written on line 38?

Comment: What do you have in line 38 (com.GenioCode.replay.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:38)?

Comment: where did you initialized the `btnSave`, it should be initialized after `setContentView()`.

Comment: @MrSus check his method findViewById()

Comment: It seem exception is due to `Context` pass `activity context` instead

Comment: Database not opened I guess. Pl check it.

Comment: open the database before the insert

Comment: please put entire class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
if(!etPassword.getText().toString().equals(etConfPassword.getText().toString())){
                        displayToast("Please confirm Password");
                    }else if(etUserName.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        displayToast("Please enter Login ID");
}else if(etPassword.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        displayToast("Please enter Password");
}else if(isExisting(etFirstName.getText().toString(), "loginId", "UserDetails")){
                        displayToast("This User already exist");
```

You fail to check beforehand whether:

```
(etPassword != null) && (etConfPassword != null) && 
(etUserName != null) && (etFirstName != null);
```

If any of those fields is null you'll get a nullpointer exception.
You have to check for those conditions first or by some other effort ensure that prior to reaching this point all relevant variables are guaranteed to be not null.

Simply preinitializing them as

```
String etPassword = "";
```

would do the trick.
It's one of those annoying things about Java. In many other languages strings start out as an empty string, not as null.